# Assigning an IP address to a jsp page

Tags: jsp

i  just want to know that is it really possible to assign an IPaddress to a jsp page which i developed in eclipse .

My requirement is i want this JSP page to open on my pc's IPAddress with a specific port instead of running on localhost or any other servers like JBOSS or redhat.

Just give me a breif if it is possible .

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You need a server of some sort to expose the JSP on a port. Which server you use depends on what is in your JSP.

- Apache web server is great for publishing simple sites exposing HTML files, PHP files and images to the web.
- Tomcat will fill the bill if you have JSPs that need support for JSTL expression language or other Java-based features.

You could get into proper J2EE servers like JBOSS but these are usually overkill for simple sites. Apache and Tomcat are easy to configure, and would be my first choice.

It might help if you tell us what is in your JSPs.

Comment: my jsp contains a table that auto updates it's data from the database,